# getchar() in a while loop immediately after scanf(" %c", ...)

Tags: c, input

There are a few questions floating around on stack overflow that, when synthesized, likely answer this question. However, I just wanted to make sure *beyond any doubt* that the following interpretation of a code segment is correct.

In "*C Programming: A Modern Approach*", the following code idiom involving a `scanf()` function and a `getchar()` function is occasionally seen. Consider the following example, taken from Page 392:

```
int main(void)
{
  char code;
  for (;;) {
    printf("Enter operation code: ");
    scanf(" %c", &code);
    while(getchar() != '\n')
      ;
.../*other stuff*/
  }
}
```

Here is my understanding of what is going on with the `getchar()` function embedded within a `while` loop.

When the user is prompted to enter a character, it is very possible that the user presses *many* buttons (e.g. `abcdefg    12 3 , . f`) into the command terminal.

In the absence of the `getchar()` line, `scanf()` (*which is embedded within an infinite loop*) would otherwise iteratively chug through that input buffer.

i.e. On the first pass, `code` would be assigned the character `'a'` and the input buffer would have `bcdefg    12 3 , . f` remaining...on the second pass through the infinite `for` loop, `code` would be assigned character `'b'` and `cdefg    12 3 , . f` would be remaining...etc.

However, by including the `getchar()` line, we are effectively **draining** the input buffer so that prior to advancing to the `\* other stuff *\` section, the input buffer is completely empty.

**Is this the correct idea**?

If it is, then my final question is **why does the `getchar()` line need to be written as `!= '\n'`**. Couldn't I have written the condition as being not equal *to literally anything*? e.g. `!= ','` or `!='d'` or `!= ' '` ...etc.

Is it just for readability (i.e. conforming to the quasi-convention of using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button to submit information to the computer)?

Thanks~

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer)

Comment: It clears the remains of the line from the `stdin`.  It will work if the `scanf` was successful or not. The next `scanf` will scan the new line.

Comment: @paulsm4 I'm not seeing why that is relevant. Wouldn't the line `while(getchar() != ','` or anything else of that nature also "consume" the new line character?...and also, the `scanf()` function here makes use of the ` %c` trick...where there is white space before the `%c`...therefore, doesn't that already address this concern?

Comment: @S.Cramer No, because any stuff left after the `,` would remain. In *normal* circumstances, there will be nothing left after a newline. However, your remark about the space before `%c` is very relevant, I think.

Comment: @AdrianMole ahhhh. Gotch ya. Thank you!

Comment: The entire `while` loop can be avoided by doing `scanf(" %c%*[^\n]\n", &code);` instead.

Comment: @dxiv various problems with that including `scanf()` not returning until a second line is entered.

Comment: "Is this the correct idea?" --> Yes but note that if `stdin` is closed, `while(getchar() != '\n') ;` never quits.  Best to look for `EOF` also.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Or EOF is reached, which makes it one better than the posted `while` loop ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is absolutely fine using `getchar()` for clearing input buffer.
I would say it is best way for clearing input bufffer rather than using `fflush` , `%*c`
or any other method.

'`\n'` simply means **ENTER KEY** (ascii value-10)
So, the while loop will run until `\n` is encountered.

input buffer would contain:

```
abcdefg    12 3 , . f\n
```

Comment: the function: `fflush()` is ONLY for output streams and `stdin` is an INPUT stream.  Using `fflush()` on an input stream is specifically stated in the C standard to be Undefined Behavior